# Can you use 아/야 on yourself?

Tags: honorific

Can you say for example: 나는 수시야 다.

If not is there any kind of way to refer to yourself in a cutesy way, like when in japanese you call youself “name”-chan?

Comment: You can say 시야 if you want. Please see my comment on jick's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your name is 수시, you can't say "나는 수시야다." - not because it's your name, but because 아/야 is only used for *calling* someone.  So it can't be used as a subject, object, complement, etc.  If you say that, people will assume that "Susiya" is your name.

On the other hand, you can say, for example, "'수시야!'라고 불러주세요."  Then you are quoting someone calling you (in the future).

Or, you can use it to talk to yourself: "수시야 정신차려!" would mean "Get yourself together, Susi!"

There is a suffix Koreans use for someone very close: -이, but unfortunately for you, the suffix only attaches to a name that ends with a consonant (i.e., 받침).  For names that end with a vowel, simply using the name by itself is considered equivalent.  (Also, it's very uncommon for -이 to attach to foreign names, even when they do end with a consonant.)

So, for example, if I have two friends 철수 and 민식, then I'd say:

> 철수가 내일 온대.  Chulsoo is coming tomorrow. (no suffix)

> 민식**이**도 내일 온대.  Minshik is coming tomorrow, too.

On the other hand, if they are my coworkers, I'd say something like:

> 철수 씨가 내일 온대. / 민식 씨도 내일 온대.

- Also, my understanding is that whether calling yourself "(name)-chan" is cute in Japan highly depends on whether people already consider you cute...

Comment: Well, gyeongsang dialect actually has this -야 thing that attaches to a name not ending with a consonant (if it ends with constant, use -아 instead). For example, 철수 can be called 수야, and 수시 can be called 시야. Apparently this exists only in gyeongsangdo, so people from other regions probably will not understand this.

Comment: And I totally agree with the last sentence. It is generally not a good idea to refer to yourself by your name. Just ask others to call you by that nickname as jick said.